# Изучение запросов с командой Join

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос: как усвоить sql запросы, а именно связку `Join`? Все остальные запросы без труда пишу, а с `Join`'ом как-то не ладится. Может, есть где подробный манул, или даже видео уроки? Хочу обладать им в совершенстве, связывать таблицы минимум 7-8штук.

Answer (score 2):

Сама столкнулась с подобной проблемой. Именно этот момент был тяжел для понимания.
Помогло размещенное на разных сайтах визуальное отображение на примере диаграмм Венна.

http://www.k-press.ru/cs/2009/3/join/join.asp - изучала на этом примере.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть 2 таблицы `А` и `Б`, при `join` по полю "х" результатом будут те записи, у которых "х" совпадает в обеих таблицах. При `right/left join` будут выбиратся все записи, но несоответсвия заполняются `null`'ми.

p.s. Уверен, sql старше нас с вами, за это время вон уже сколько мануалов напечатали и строк набрали, загуглите. Xотя бы на вики почитайте :)
p.s.s. То, что у вас есть необходимость делать `join` 7-8 таблиц, скорее всего означает, что у вас неправильно спроэктирована (как минимум неэфективно) работа с БД. Или же структура БД неправильная. Поищите "СУБД три нормальных формы".

**UPDATE**: примеры:

**inner join:**

```
create table a as select 1 as x from dual;
create table b as select 6 as x from dual;

insert into a values (2);
insert into a values (3);
insert into a values (4);
insert into a values (5);

insert into b values (7);
insert into b select * from a where x > 2;

select * from a;
         X
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5

select * from b;
         X
----------
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7

select a.x as a, b.x as b from a, b where a.x = b.x;
         A          B
---------- ----------
         3          3
         4          4
         5          5
```

**left outer join** (частичто используем данные с предыдущего примера, правый аналогичный левому прост строки которых нет заполняются нулями с другой стороны)

```
insert into a values (1);
insert into a values (2);
insert into a values (2);
insert into a values (3);
insert into a values (3);
insert into a values (3);

drop table b;
create table b as select 1 as x, '1234567890' as count from dual where 1!=1;
insert into b values (1, 'one');
insert into b values (2, 'two');
insert into b values (3, 'three');

select x, count (*) as count from a group by x order by x;
         X      COUNT
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          3
         3          4
         4          1
         5          1

select * from b;
         X COUNT
---------- ----------
         1 one
         2 two
         3 three

select t.x as a, t.count, NVL(b.count, 'null') as text 
from ( select x, count (*) as count from a group by x ) t 
left outer join b on (b.x = t.x) order by t.x;
         A      COUNT TEXT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2 one
         2          3 two
         3          4 three
         4          1 null
         5          1 null
```

Comment: Поищите и сразу задумайтесь надо ли их соблюдать :D<br>
Особенно 3юю...

Comment: 3я самая нормальная))) А вообще это имеет смысл все таки...

Comment: Конечно же мне не придется соединять 7-8 таблиц,но почему я сказал именно 7-8? просто после них соединять 2-4 будет казаться очень простым  делом)

Comment: тоже интересен этот вопрос, особенно, если есть еще и group by

Comment: Странное явления получается, вот такой запрос работает  
<code>SELECT * 
FROM tovar
INNER JOIN Manufacturer ON tovar.manufacturer = Manufacturer.id  </code>  

а вот такой нет    

<code>SELECT * 
FROM tovar
FULL OUTER JOIN Manufacturer ON tovar.manufacturer = Manufacturer.id</code>

Comment: FULL OUTER
мне такое и не встречалось =)

Comment: если речь о mysql то FULL OUTER JOIN и не должен работать...